# Threading inside class with atomics and mutex c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, mutex, atomic

I wrote this sample program to mimic what I'm trying to do in a larger program.

I have some data that will come from the user and be passed into a thread for some processing. I am using mutexes around the data the flags to signal when there is data.

Using the lambda expression, is a pointer to *this send to the thread? I seem to be getting the behavior I expect in the cout statement.

Are the mutexes used properly around the data?

Is putting the atomics and mutexes as a private member of the class a good move?

foo.h

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();

    void StartThread();
    void StopThread();
    void SendData();

private:
    std::atomic<bool> dataFlag;
    std::atomic<bool> runBar;
    void bar();
    std::thread t1;
    std::vector<int> data;
    std::mutex mx;
};
```

foo.c

```
#include "FooClass.h"
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo()
{
    dataFlag = false;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    StopThread();
}

void Foo::StartThread()
{
    runBar = true;
    t1 = std::thread([=] {bar(); });
    return;
}

void Foo::StopThread()
{
    runBar = false;

    if(t1.joinable())
        t1.join();

    return;
}

void Foo::SendData()
{
    mx.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        data.push_back(i);
    }
    mx.unlock();
    dataFlag = true;
}

void Foo::bar()
{
    while (runBar)
    {
        if(dataFlag)
        {
            mx.lock();
            for(auto it = data.begin(); it < data.end(); ++it)
            {
                std::cout << *it << '\n';
            }
            mx.unlock();
            dataFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "FooClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    Foo foo1;

    std::cout << "Type anything to end thread" << std::endl;

    foo1.StartThread();
    foo1.SendData();

    // type something to end threads
    char a;
        std::cin >> a;

    foo1.StopThread();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use std::lock_guard<mx> instead of manually calling mx.lock()/unlock()

Comment: When you start thread you should either `join()` it or `detach()`

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich why? he's `join()`ing later...

Comment: I prefer to save `detach` for weird occasions

Comment: I would move your assignments to `dataFlag` to within the lock. Right now I can see potential issues with it being outside.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, because you will get `std::terminate()` in `thread` destructor in you dont't. For example If you got an exception in this case

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich yes, but that isn't the case here. The thread is joined upon `Foo` destruction anyway

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, O yeah, you're rigth. Anyway it is a good practice always call either detach or join

Comment: @vu1p3n0x, Ok, I will update the code to use dataFlag within the lock as things may get out of order. dataFlag is an atomic, but that wont' ensure any race conditions with the data wont' occur.

Comment: Having a loop that burns the CPU while it waits for something is not good. Using an atomic for `dataFlag` when the data it interacts with is protected by a mutex anyway is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ensure that the thread is joined using RAII techniques? Check.

All data access/modification is either protected through `atomic`s or `mutex`s? Check.

Mutex locking uses `std::lock_guard`? Nope. Using `std::lock_guard` wraps your `lock()` and `unlock()` calls with RAII. This ensures that even if an exception occurs while within the lock, that the lock is released.

> Is putting the atomics and mutexes as a private member of the class a good move?

Its neither good nor bad, but in this scenario, where `Foo` is a wrapper for a `std::thread` that does work and controls the synchronization, it makes sense.

> Using the lambda expression, is a pointer to *this send to the thread?

Yes, you can also do `t1 = std::thread([this]{bar();});` to make it more explicit.

As it stands, with your `dataFlag` assignments after the locks, you may encounter problems. If you call `SendData` twice such that `bar` processes the first one but is halted before setting `dataFlag = false` so that the second call adds the data, sets the flag to `true` only to have `bar` set it back to `false`. Then, you'll have data that has been "sent" but `bar` doesn't think there's anything to process.

There may be other tricky situations, but this was just one example; moving it into the lock clears up that problem.

for example, your `SendData` should look like:

```
void Foo::SendData()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mx);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        data.push_back(i);
    }
    dataFlag = true;
}
```